# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-paranoid

In terminal:

```
2.2.0 :001 > sr=ServiceRequest.only_deleted.where(:id=>57)
```

`=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<ServiceRequest id: 57, sr_number: "SRN57", email: "xxx@gmail.com", phone: "54545121", subject: "change of address", body: "sdssssssssssssss", status_id: 1, request_type_id: 1, customer_id: nil, created_at: "2015-04-24 13:06:52", updated_at: "2015-04-28 05:13:05", deleted_at: "2015-04-28 05:13:05">]>`

`2.2.0 :004 > sr.destroy`

`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

I am using `paranoia` gem in my application.I want to destroy this record from the database.How do i destroy this record, please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find singular `ServiceRequest`. So, instead of `where`, use `find`:

```
sr = ServiceRequest.only_deleted.find(57)
```

or `find_by` if you don't want it to raise an error if the record isn't found:

```
sr = ServiceRequest.only_deleted.find_by(id: 57)
```

then you can call `destroy` on it:

```
sr.destroy
```

But it seems you need to actually destroy object from DB, since it's already marked as "destroyed", so you should rather use:

```
sr.really_destroy!
```

Comment: I have used really_destroy before but it does't work with where clause.But this is all done with find_by.Why it does't work with where clause?

Comment: @Udaykumardas because it's designed to work on instance, not on relation.